# How does the current get distributed in a Serial-Parallel battery pack?

Tags: batteries, current, battery-charging, parallel, series

I was following a tutorial that tries to emulate the voltage drop in a battery pack with cells in parallel and series (in a 6s2p connection). The pack looks like this:

[image]

Let's say that one applies 20A to this pack and all the cells are the same. Say, 2.6Ah and 3.6V nominal voltage. From a practical point of view, one would expect for each cell to be receiving the same current, otherwise it would imbalance everything and age some cells faster than the other and the performance would drop.

My question is... How is the current distributed here? Is it 1.6A/cell (20A/12cells?) or how does it get distributed within the pack? Or is it 10A/cell, since there are only two sets in parallel?

Answer (score 3):

No, they won't be the same.

You get 20A flowing via the whole circuit, and since the whole circuit consists of packs of two paralleled cells connected in series, there will be 20A flowing via each pack of two parallel cells.

So each cell should have 10A flowing through it, but as the cells are not identical, the current is distributed unevenly via the two cells due to their differences and manufacturing tolerances.

Comment: You’re right that the currents won’t be identical, but they will be quite similar; in particular with lithium cells the voltage drops significantly as the cells discharge, so a cell with a higher voltage will tend to contribute more current and it will therefore discharge a little faster and it’s voltage will drop, so the pack will self-balance to a degree.  With other chemistries this tends to happen when the pack is fully charged or discharged, but to a lesser degree at other times since the cell voltages vary less with state of charge.

Comment: Let's assume that all the cells are perfect. Will each cell get 10A? The way I'm seeing it after your explanation is like this. 20A is applied to the first cells through the positive terminal. There, it splits into 10A and 10A, which go into the first two cells, then distribute to the rest. Is that a correct interpretation? Then the next question is... what happens when that current reaches the next parallel connection? Won't it split again? As you can see, I am just guessing and trying to use my intuition. Any details and explanation would help a lot to understand it. Thank you!

Comment: If cells are assumed identical, then 10A would flow through each cell.

Answer (score 1):

> 3.6V nominal voltage

OK, 3.6V: I'm assuming lithium cells.

Due to the fact that lithium cells have a fairly steep positive voltage slope with respect to charge level, parallel cells will tend to settle at the same charge state,  even wildly dissimilar cells will balance by this means.

Thus because the cells have the same charge state (percentage full) assuming the cells have the same capacity they will have the same current flowing.